# xrdp broken after install

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

Hi I installed xrdp a while back and it worked fine, I then tried to follow this tutorial to enable the clipboard (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9285). I could then no longer RDP into the server and only connect via Putty.

I've tried to run the following commands to remove rdp

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove xrdp
sudo apt-get purge xrdp
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove xrdp
```

And then reboot and reinstall xrdp

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

It then fails and i receive the following error:

```
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)

Oct 19 17:06:15 iomad-test systemd[1]: Dependency failed for xrdp daemon.
Oct 19 17:06:15 iomad-test systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Job xrdp.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 19 17:07:27 iomad-test systemd[1]: Dependency failed for xrdp daemon.
Oct 19 17:07:27 iomad-test systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Job xrdp.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 19 17:10:09 iomad-test systemd[1]: Stopped xrdp daemon.
Oct 19 17:11:46 iomad-test systemd[1]: Dependency failed for xrdp daemon.
Oct 19 17:11:46 iomad-test systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Job xrdp.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 19 17:16:19 iomad-test systemd[1]: Dependency failed for xrdp daemon.
Oct 19 17:16:19 iomad-test systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Job xrdp.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xrdp
```

Any ideas on how to reinstall xrdp and get it working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I got stuck in the same situation but was able to restore to the xrdp from the repository. I spend many hours trying to find out how to undo the script.

Step 1. Remove the service files and the backup files.

```
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/xrdp*
```

Step 2. Remove the new xrdp binaries (to make sure they do not end up in the classpath of the service).

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/xrdp*
sudo rm /usr/local/sbin/xrdp*
```

Step 3. Remove keys (got a 'security exception' in the client before removal)

```
sudo rm /etc/xrdp/rsakeys.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide additional information about how to remove the xrdp files when performing a custom installation, there is in fact a post that has been published in December 2017 (please check here http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11454)

Based on your install method, you can uninstall the xrdp installation using apt command (if using xrdp package provided by Canonical or if you compile from source using the checkinstall option...

If you are simply running the custom installation script, you simply need to delete the files in the appropriate location. To summarize actions

sudo systemctl stop xrdp
rm -r /etc/xrdp 
rm -r /usr/local/sbin/xrdp 
rm /var/run/xrdp.pid
rm /var/run/xrdp-sesman.pid
sudo systemctl disable xrdp

Hope this help 
Till Next time

Comment: What I don't understand (I just encountered the same problem) is: why was it installed in the first place if I am expected to uninstall it? Can't I just find a way to have the new xrdp-service working?