# After giving admin permissions to a user, xrdp shows a black screen

Tags: 22.04, xrdp, policykit

My host is an Ubuntu 22.04.1 machine on Oracle server, my client is an Ubuntu 20.04.5.
The connection was established via xrdp 0.9.17 using Xorg with no issue. Following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154747/how-can-i-give-permission-to-a-user-be-able-to-unlock-users-gui-to-create-new-us), I tried to give admin permissions to the single user I have on my host. In particular, I set a password for that user and created the file

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/46-user-admin.pkla
```

with the following content:

```
[Authorize admin control of user settings]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.accounts.*;org.gnome.controlcenter.user-accounts.*
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultAny=yes
```

and rebooted. After this and a successful log in with xrdp, I get a black screen. Trying to log in with a wrong user or a misspelled password, I get an error as expected, but with the right credentials there is a plain black screen. SSH connection is working just fine.

I tried to remove completely xrdp (usual purge and manual erase of [few folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966405/xrdp-broken-after-install)), reinstall it, reconfiguring it (changing port protocol to tcp). At first the status of the xrdp service is OK, but after a failed login attempt I get:

```
me@me:~$ sudo service xrdp status
xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-11-10 09:35:06 UTC; 2min 9s ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
    Process: 2578 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2586 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2587 (xrdp)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 28694)
     Memory: 812.0K
        CPU: 42ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
             └─2587 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [INFO ] xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 7864320 MB cache entries 2000
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [WARN ] Client Capability: not enough orders supported by client, client wants off screen bitmap but offscreen bitmaps disabled
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000407.ini
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000407 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [INFO ] connecting to sesman ip x.x.x.x port 3350
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [INFO ] sesman connect ok
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [INFO ] sending login info to session manager, please wait...
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed
Nov 14 09:36:26 me xrdp[2654]: [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed
```

and looking at the Xorg sessions, there are so many entries:

```
me@me:~$ xauth list
me/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  xxx
me/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  yyy
me/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  zzz
me/unix:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  www
me/unix:14  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  uuu
```

I tried to dig a bit more for the error `trans_write_copy_s failed`, but I think there is something wrong with my user.

I would appreciate any input from you. Thank you.